# How to properly pass context to AsyncTask and then to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm working on app that will use biometric as an option to login. Before I use the actual biometric prompt I need to check one thing from server - I use AsyncTask to do it. So, to sum up - I invoke AsyncTask from Parent Activity (login.java), and then AsyncTask uses biometricUtils.java class, that makes biometric prompt. The point is, I keep passing null instead of context to biometricUtils.java:
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.concurrent.Executor android.content.Context.getMainExecutor()' on a null object reference at biometricUtils.<init>(biometricUtils.java:34)`

I have no idea to pass the context correctly.

Here's my code:

**login.java**

```java
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        final boolean flag = false;
        final String androidID = bundle.getString("androidID");
        final Activity thisActivity = this;
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // login using biometrics
        Button btnBiometricLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnBiometricLogin);
        btnBiometricLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAndroidID async = new checkAndroidID(context);
                async.getParentActivity(thisActivity);
                async.setFlag(flag);
                async.execute(androidID);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**checkAndroidID.java**

```java
public class checkAndroidID extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    openHTTP openHTTP = new openHTTP();
    requestHTTP requests = new requestHTTP();

    Activity parentActivity;
    private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;
    Boolean flag;

    public checkAndroidID(Context context){
        contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public void getParentActivity(Activity parentActivity){
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }


    public void setFlag (Boolean flag){
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = openHTTP.prepareConnection("url");
            String json = "{ \"androidID\": \"" + strings[0] + "\" }";
            requests.sendData(json, httpConn);
            return requests.receiveData(httpConn);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        String[] result = s.split(";");

        Context ctx = contextRef.get();

        if (result[0].equals("TRUE")) flag = true;
        if (!flag) Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Biometric authentication is now unavailable." +
                " Please login using username and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            biometricUtils biometrics = new biometricUtils(ctx);
            biometrics.getParentActivity(parentActivity);
            biometrics.getUsername(result[1]);
            biometrics.inovkeBiometricPrompt();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

and **biometricUtlis.java**

```java
public class biometricUtils {

    Activity parentActivity;
    String username;
    Context context;

    public void getParentActivity(Activity parentActivity){
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }

    public void getUsername(String s){
        this.username = s;
    }

    public biometricUtils(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    // creating a variable for our Executor
    Executor executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context); // LINE 34
    // this will give us result of AUTHENTICATION
    final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt((FragmentActivity) parentActivity, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
        }

        // THIS METHOD IS CALLED WHEN AUTHENTICATION IS SUCCESS
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            Intent intent = new Intent(parentActivity.getApplicationContext(), tmp.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", username);
            parentActivity.startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        }
    });
    // creating a variable for our promptInfo
    // BIOMETRIC DIALOG
    final BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder().setTitle("Biometrical login")
            .setDescription("Place your fingerprint on scanner to proceed").setNegativeButtonText("Cancel").build();

    public void inovkeBiometricPrompt() {
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Executor executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)` That line is on the wrong place. You should call that function in the constructor. Not there as there is no context yet.

Comment: Which function ? You mean smth like this: 
```java
    public biometricUtils(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.context);
    }
```

Comment: And... did it help?

Comment: No, I still pass null parameters (both parentActivity and executor) and recieved erorr: ```FragmentActivity must not be null.```

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with that context i think.

Comment: I don't even know what I am doing wrong. How to change the question to make it more appropriate to this problem ?